# How can we cascade an exception when methods are annotated with @Transaction in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-jdbc

Looking at the example below:

We have the `UserSerice` class that has a method `invoice()` which calls another method `createPdf` in the `InvoiceService`.

I'd like to handle the `DataIntegrityViolationException` if thrown in the `invoice`- which is the calling method

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceService invoiceService;

    @Transactional
    public void invoice() {
        invoiceService.createPdf();
        // send invoice as email, etc.
    }
}

@Service
public class InvoiceService {

    @Transactional
    public void createPdf() throws DataIntegrityViolationException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I tried to use the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)` on the `createPdf` to force spring to use once JDBC connection, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is what one can do to fix. The DataIntegrityViolationException is sent back to the calling service

```
@Service
public class InvoiceService {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createPdf() throws DataIntegrityViolationException {
        // ...
    }
}
```